# React/Redux : How can i access a certain property and update it?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm trying to update the value of a property and I'm not able to do it.

Here's my reducer:

```
import { LOAD_BINNACLE_NOTES, BINNACLE_NOTE_REVIEW, ADD_NEW_NOTE, RESET_BINNACLE_NOTES } from "../Actions/notes.actions";

export const notes = (state = [], action) => {
   const { type, payload } = action;
   switch (type) {
      case LOAD_BINNACLE_NOTES:
         const { binnacleNotes } = payload;
         return {
            ...state,
            binnacleNotes,
         };
      case ADD_NEW_NOTE:
         const { id, date, binnacle_note, responsible, attachments, constructor_review, super_review, dro_review, timestamp } = payload;
         return {
            binnacleNotes: [
               ...state.binnacleNotes,
               {
                  id,
                  date,
                  binnacle_note,
                  responsible,
                  attachments,
                  constructor_review,
                  super_review,
                  dro_review,
                  timestamp,
               },
            ],
         };

      case BINNACLE_NOTE_REVIEW:
         const { noteNumber, role } = payload;
         return state.binnacleNotes.map((note) => {
            switch (role) {
               case "super":
                  // return { ...state, binnacleNotes: { super_review: 1 } };

                  return {
                     ...state,
                     binnacleNotes: state.binnacleNotes.map((note) => (note.id === noteNumber ? { ...notes, super_review: 1 } : note)),
                  };

               case "dro":
                  if (note.id == noteNumber) {
                     return {
                        ...note,
                        binnacleNotes: state.binnacleNotes.map((note) => (note.id === action.id ? { ...notes, dro_review: 1 } : note)),
                     };
                  } else {
                     return note;
                  }

               case "constructor":
                  if (note.id == noteNumber) {
                     return {
                        ...note,
                        binnacleNotes: state.notes.binnacleNotes.map((note) => (note.id === action.id ? { ...notes, constructor_review: 1 } : note)),
                     };
                  } else {
                     return note;
                  }

               default:
                  return state;
            }
         });
      case RESET_BINNACLE_NOTES:
         return (state = []);
      default:
         return state;
   }
};
```

And I'm trying to perform the update with the BINNACLE_NOTE_REVIEW:

```
case BINNACLE_NOTE_REVIEW:
         const { noteNumber, role } = payload;
         return state.binnacleNotes.map((note) => {
            switch (role) {
               case "super":
                  // return { ...state, binnacleNotes: { super_review: 1 } };

                  return {
                     ...state,
                     binnacleNotes: state.binnacleNotes.map((note) => (note.id === noteNumber ? { ...notes, super_review: 1 } : note)),
                  };

               case "dro":
                  if (note.id == noteNumber) {
                     return {
                        ...note,
                        binnacleNotes: state.binnacleNotes.map((note) => (note.id === action.id ? { ...notes, dro_review: 1 } : note)),
                     };
                  } else {
                     return note;
                  }

               case "constructor":
                  if (note.id == noteNumber) {
                     return {
                        ...note,
                        binnacleNotes: state.notes.binnacleNotes.map((note) => (note.id === action.id ? { ...notes, constructor_review: 1 } : note)),
                     };
                  } else {
                     return note;
                  }

               default:
                  return state;
            }
         });
```

The state of my notes reducer looks like this:

[image]

And after trying to update the value, the state looks like this:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `BINNACLE_NOTE_REVIEW` case you still need to shallow merge it with the existing state. The default case for `role` in the mapping should not merge in the outer state, it should merge the current `note`.

```
case BINNACLE_NOTE_REVIEW:
  const { noteNumber, role } = payload;
  
  switch (role) {
    case "super":
      return {
        ...state,
        binnacleNotes: state.binnacleNotes.map((note) => (
          note.id === noteNumber 
            ? { ...note, super_review: 1 }
            : note
        )),
      };

    case "dro":
      return {
        ...state,
        binnacleNotes: state.binnacleNotes.map((note) => (
          note.id === noteNumber
            ? { ...note, dro_review: 1 }
            : note
        )),
      };

    case "constructor":
      return {
        ...state,
        binnacleNotes: state.binnacleNotes.map((note) => (
          note.id === noteNumber
            ? { ...note, constructor_review: 1 }
            : note
        )),
      };

     default:
        return state;
   }
```

Since each case is applying the same logic and just specifying a different property you can reduce the code and make it more **DRY**

```
case BINNACLE_NOTE_REVIEW:
  const { noteNumber, role } = payload;

  return {
    ...state,
    binnacleNotes: state.binnacleNotes.map((note) => {
      if (note.id === noteNumber) {
        switch(role) {
          case "super":
            return { ...note, super_review: 1 };
          case "dro":
            return { ...note, dro_review: 1 };
          case "constructor":
            return { ...note, constructor_review: 1 };
          default:
            return note;
        }
      }
      return note;
    }),
  };
```